# Raspberry Pi 3b+ serial communication on both console and hardware issue

Tags: serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I am a bit new to raspberry pi but I think I managed to enable(kind of) serial comm yet I am getting confused as it seems to be using console as well as modem communication at the same time.

Below is my code:

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyAMA0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout = 1
)

while 1:
    ser.write('AT'+'\r')
    time.sleep(1)
    print(ser.read(10))
```

below is the output I get:

```
Linux 9 raspberrypi AT
OK
Login incorrectraspberrypi login:
AT
OK

Login incorrectraspberrypi login:
AT
OK
Login incorrectraspberrypi login:
AT
OK

AT
OK

Login incorrectraspberrypi login:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sim808AT.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(ser.read(10))
  File "/usr/lib..." read
    'device reports readiness to read but returned no data'
```

then it disconnects...

Comment: No ideas, or my question isn't clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, to setup serial without console:

Revert anything you have changed to do with serial (any additional lines in \boot\cmdline.txt, \boot\config.txt, etc). Note: the boot partition can be accessed with a MicroSloth OS!

Run `sudo raspi-config`. 
Under "5 Interfacing Options" -> "P6 Serial", choose no for shell and yes for port hardware.

Reboot and test.

BTW, hardware serial is now ttyAMA0 rather than ttyS0.

I actually found your post looking for a solution of my own; I am having problems with serial using the latest Pi image (October 2018), but I digress ;)